# Ubuntu 22.04 blinking cursor after driver update

Tags: boot, drivers, 22.04

This morning I updated the drivers (with a command to update all the drivers).
When this evening I booted Ubuntu, I was surprised with a `ALERT UUID=xxx does not exist, dropping ti a shell` and got stuck with `initramfs`.

After fiddling a bit (turned off VMD from the BIOS and a bunch of other stuff) now I'm stuck with the black screen with blinking cursor.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> works, but I can't seem to get any further. I really don't know what to do and I need to do stuff.